# how to remove stopwords from a text in pre processing of spark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, stanford-nlp, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml, sparkcore

I have a requirement to pre process the data in the spark before running the algorithms
One of the pre processing logic was to remove the stopwords from the text. I tried with spark StopWordsRemover.  StopWordsRemover requires input and output should be Array[String]. After running the program the final column output is shown as collection of strings, i would require a plain string.

My code as follows.

```
val tokenizer: RegexTokenizer = new RegexTokenizer().setInputCol("raw").setOutputCol("token")
val stopWordsRemover = new StopWordsRemover().setInputCol("token").setOutputCol("final")
stopWordsRemover.setStopWords(stopWordsRemover.getStopWords ++ customizedStopWords)
val tokenized: DataFrame = tokenizer.transform(hiveDF)
val transformDF = stopWordsRemover.transform(tokenized)
```

Actual Output

```
["rt messy support need help with bill"]
```

Required Output:

```
rt messy support need help with bill
```

My output should be like a string but not as array of string. Is there any way to do this. I require the output of the column in the dataframe as string.

Also I would need suggestion on the below options to remove stopwords from the text in the spark program.

1. StopWordsRemover from SparkMlib
2. Standford CoreNLP Library.

Which of the option gives better performance when parsing huge files.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this to get string instead of array-of-strings - `df.collect()[0]` - if you are sure only first item is in your interest.

However, that should not be any issue here as long as you traverse the array and get each items there.

Ultimately HiveDF will give you RDD[String] - and it becomes Array[String] when you convert from RDD.